# Is there a way to Run MS Test using Gallio?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, gallio

I have looked at other questions similar to this and they all seem to be Pre-RTM of Visual Studio 2010 (or they don't have a real answer).

I have downloaded the latest version of Gallio and I am trying to run my MS Test Project using it.

I added Gallio to my References in my MS Test Project then did a full build and then opened the compiled dll in Gallio.

I then then tried to run my tests and they don't run.  I don't get any errors, just that they fail.

It says `218 tests - 0 passed - 1 failed - 0 inconclusive - 0 skipped`.

I checked the run time logs and it says that it needs Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell which is disabled.  I checked the plugins and this is that that one says:

**Visual Studio Integration Shell**
Provides a framework for hosting Gallio plugins within Visual Studio.
**Disabled**: The plugin enable condition was not satisfied.  Please note that this is the intended behavior for plugins that must be hosted inside third party applications in order to work.  Enable condition: '${process:DEVENV.EXE} or ${process:VSTESTHOST.EXE} or ${process:QTAGENT.EXE} or ${process:QTAGENT32.EXE} or ${process:QTDCAGENT.EXE} or ${process:QTDCAGENT32.EXE} or ${process:MSTEST.EXE}'.

I am not even running inside visual studio, but it sees it as needed.  I have devenv.exe running (both Gallio and Devenv.exe are running under my account).

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug fixed](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=664) in [build 3.2.587](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/) an later. It did prevent the Gallio test runners to properly execute MSTest-based tests outside the Visual Studio environment (e.g. from Echo or Icarus)

There is also a quick workaround (from Kevin Ortman) if you need to make it work right now. You might just delete the whole attribute **enableCondition** in the following plugin definition data files (at line 3 or 4 I believe):

- `Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell90.plugin`
- `Gallio.VisualStudio.Tip90.plugin`
- `Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell.plugin`

Or if you are working with VS2010:

- `Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell100.plugin`
- `Gallio.VisualStudio.Tip100.plugin`
- `Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell.plugin`